Polarization by Polaroid
A Polaroid is made up of slits aligned in a specific direction.
Before passing through the Polaroid, electric field and magnetic field vectors of light (suppose from a bulb) aligned in random directions at different times.
But, after passing through the slits of the Polaroid, we see that the vectors are parallel to the slit.
Fields aligned in the perpendicular direction are destroyed. How does this really happen? How can a wall nullify a force exerted towards it?

Drawings that depict "polarization" often show something that looks like an array of slits. But, that is not how Polaroid film is made. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polaroid_(polarizer)

@SolomonSlow that figure of slits was really misleading . Thx for indicating towards the concept and answer
